# Fedora 35 firewalld add port and service problem

Tags: fedora, firewalld

Hello i just installeed Fedora and I'm trying to open the port 20190
I do everything just as normal but when i use `firewall-cmd --list-all` to see if the port is opened, i see nothing !!!

This is what i do to open the port

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=20190/tcp
```

Then i reload it

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Then this is the `firewall-cmd --list-all` result which my ports is empty !!!!!!

```
FedoraServer (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the port 20190 to the zone public.

By default, --list-all default to the "default zone (FedoraServer)". See the target in default in your output.

Explicitly mention public to see the rules for the zone "public" like below

> firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public

Additional tip:

If you want to make public as the default zone, use

> firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=public